Why do I get a FileNotFoundException when the file obviously exists?
I have a piece of C# code in which I try to list some files from a directory. When listing the files I get a FileNotFoundException (which is not caught yet), but I don't understand why...
    try
    {
        String[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directory);
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
        long size = fi.Length;
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cannot enumerate files from " + directory);
    }

The value for directory is
D:\_temporary_files\2024_temporary_files_temporary_file-2024-07-21_-_author_unknown_length_unknown_size_unknown\2024_temporary_files_temporary_file-2024-07-21_-_author_unknown_length_unknown_size_unknown

The file which gives me the FileNotFoundException is
D:\_temporary_files\2024_temporary_files_temporary_file-2024-07-21_-_author_unknown_length_unknown_size_unknown\2024_temporary_files_temporary_file-2024-07-21_-_author_unknown_length_unknown_size_unknown\2024_temporary_files_temporary_file-2024-07-21_-_17-11-00-0001.dat

I tried to recursively list files in directories, starting from the root D:, but got a FileNotFoundException when I hit the above file/directory.
I suspect it may have something to do with the length of path/filename, yet I can see, list, edit the file perfectly fine in Windows (10), notepad, other editors, other file explorers, whatever.
Since all other software tools seem to have no problem handling this file, why am I getting this exception in C#?
Thanks!
Edit: in my haste I left out the piece of code which generates the FileNotFoundException - getting the length of the file throws the error.

Directory.GetFiles() gives you a FileNotFoundException?

Seeing this is a temp folder, is there a race condition going on (files being removed while trying to list the folder's files)?

@gunr2171 No, I left out some code (my mistake), the error is thrown when I get the length of the file.
This is not a temp folder, nothing is being written to or removed from the directory when I run the program. And yes, I can see the irony in the filenames, but that is out of my control.

Does fi.Exists give you false if you execute it before fi.Length? And I assume if you take fi.FullName's value, copy it into the Open dialog for Notepad, it will open just fine?

Your filename supposedly contains a colon. Are you really, really sure it does? How did you create such a file? (It's possible that if it's been created in some really odd way, that most Windows APIs won't be able to access it. I'd definitely try to avoid such filenames..)

@gunr2171 I've added fi.Exists and added some logging in the else part. For each file in that particular subdirectory, I get a "File does not exist" message...
Notepad opens the file, but not when I open the file with it's complete path - then it says file not found as well, and I see a truncated filename in the open file dialog.
When I open the file inside the directory by typing "notepad filename", it does open.
So I'm guessing the length of the path and filename are a problem for other software as well, and not just my program.

@JonSkeet The filename does not contain colons, my mistake - while typing the filename I assumed the name to hold a timestamp and typed it as such, with colons. I altered my question.
I've asked how and why these files were created like this, and they replied that the entire directory came as an archive. The archive is placed in a directory named for said archive, and unpacks in a subdirectory named for the archive, which results in the repeating names in the directory structure.
I'm going to take gunr2171's advice and use fi.Exists and your suggestion to avoid these paths as a solution.

Another option to explore would be if you asked folks to leave the actual archive there itself - you'd probably be able to get the files from the archive. That may or may not be helpful for your actual situation, but just thought I'd mention it as a possible option.

@Deekay - In your example - file is has not been initialized or is null. Are you missing some code?

This question is similar to: How to deal with files with a name longer than 259 characters?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@user246821 My question was not how to deal with files with a name longer than 259 characters, rather than why I was getting a FileNotFoundException while other programs were able to handle the situation without a problem. Also, when I posted the question I got a LOT of similar questions, yet they all were focused on Java, I was unable to find info on C#. In hindsight, length of the filename turned out to be the problem.

@Deekay: In hindsight, length of the filename turned out to be the problem: When programming one must be aware of the limitations of both the programming language one is using, as well as, the limitations of the operating system. Also, when troubleshooting, one mustn't get too focused on the error message generated, but rather use it as a starting point.

The following may be of interest: Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces

As stated in Maximum Path Length Limitation:

In the Windows API [...], the maximum length for a path is MAX_PATH, which is defined as 260 characters.

Your path including the file name has a length of 270 characters.
You might still be able to see the file in the Windows Explorer, but some file operations might fail.
While this limit has been removed in Windows 10 version 1607, some APIs are still limited by the historical limit.
See also:

PathTooLongException Class
How to deal with files with a name longer than 259 characters?
Best way to resolve file path too long exception

